# How to add a template to an ASP.Net project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner on ASP.Net MVC. I want to add a template for my project but I don't know what to do! So can someone please help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set layout manually from the template header and footer. After that, you can create pages and add respective content from template.

Comment: Sorry could you explain please? the model I want to use contains js, css, html files ... how to add all these files to my project?

Comment: Create one asp.net project, add the content folder and put all css, js, fonts etc folders inside that folder. Refer those scripts and js inside layout or make bundling. 
You can check the default project structure and follow the same for your reference by creating a new project in visual studio( File-> New Project -> Asp.net web application -> (Select MVC/ Web Form as per your requirement).

Comment: thanks, I created already an asp.net mvc project, so chould i put these files on the wwwroot folder or i have to create another folder and copy scripts & css file in there ?7

Comment: You have created asp.net core project, so put those files in wwwroot folder.